# Add a framework library in XCode, without the need to adding again after each change?

Tags: swift, xcode

I can drag/drop a framework's build output into my project, and it's added there and I have access to my framework methods and classes.

Yet any time I build framework, I need to remove it from my project and add it again, because it *copies* the framework output into my project.

What I want is to be able to link them together, so that whenever I change framework, I access it from my project without the need to delete it and add it again.

What should I do?

Comment: you could drag/drop the framework project inside your app and just use the build if you want to release your app and/or framework

Comment: Are your framework target and your project both inside the same .xcworkspace? There I do not have to drag-and-drop, but just add it in the project-targets’ settings under General at the bottom with the plus-button to the linked frameworks. I think the project-target will only be buildable though when the .xcworkspace is open so it can get the framework-dependency anew..

Comment: No, our projects are not in one xcworkspace. One project is in folder /libraries, while the other project is in /projects.

Comment: Then I guess you already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148873/how-to-add-xcode-framework-from-external-folder), specifically the first answers’ comments?

Comment: ld: framework not found Validation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @ali fallah: Did you use Embed binary? Just linking does not seem to be enough, the framework is probably loaded on invocation and since its not a system library cannot be loaded from the system, but rather must be embedded in a Bundle to be loaded from there. The link above shows how. Otherwise I’m out of answers