# "Library not loaded: @rpath error" frameworks linking issue within framework - iOS XCODE

Tags: ios, frameworks, dynamic-linking

I have two frameworks linked within another framework. E.g. Player.framework and Score.framework. Both framework linked inside to Game.framework. All are in Objective-c.

Player.framework & Score.framework are manually copied from respective product folder and pasted inside the Game.framework.

Error: 
Test cases inside Game.framework only works when **Player.framework & Score.framework are available in "/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/" folder.**

If i delete derivedData manually and tried to execute test-case of Game.framework, i am getting error

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/Player.framework/Player. 
Program ended with exit code: 82
```

As i have already pasted Player.framework & Score.framework inside Game.framework and sets framework search path correctly why its depend on "Deriveddata" folder?

Answer (score -5):

You need to:
Embedded binaries are binary files that are copied to your application bundle when you build the project. Use embedded binaries when your application relies on third-party frameworks so people can use your application without needing those frameworks installed on their machine. Embedded binaries keep users from having to manually install third-party frameworks. Your application uses the framework you embedded.

[image]

Comment: a) You've just copied the text from someone else's answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173529/what-are-embedded-binaries-in-xcode and b) it doesn't even attempt to answer the question.